# How can I filter unique lines based on a substring?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, uniq

If I have a set of URLs in a file like:

http://example.com/do?foo=bar&etc=123

http://example.com/do?etc=456&foo=bar

I want to filter this out so that there's only one url for each unique value of the 'foo' parameter.  The rest of the URL doesn't matter, the only important thing to me is that I don't have two or more lines with the same value of 'foo'.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you fail? This is not a script-writing site, we only advise people on how to correct mistakes they run into.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with awk, I guess you are familiar with it at some level, for example you know that you can set the field separator to a set of characters at the command line (and elsewhere) like **-F'[?&]'**.

Also, you may know that the **NF** variable contains the number of the fields parsed in the current input record (line) and you can loop from 2 to **NF** with a C-style **for(...;...;...)** to find the **foo=xxx** field.

And the best thing that can serve you here is the associative array of awk (called dictionary or hash or map in other contexts) in which you can store a value in the index and check if a value is already in the array as an index and make decisions accordingly. Such as:

```
if ( ! (value in myarray) ) {
   print thelinevalueisfrom
   myarray[value] = 1 # just to register we have seen value for later usage
}
```

Basically, this is all you need here.